# Best way of handling unknown types received from Firebase's Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently using Firebase for my swift project, and when I retrieve the data from Firebase their type is `Any`. So, there is no guarantee that I will received the type I am expecting, especially if I work with extra people that can edit the database datatypes in Firebase console. My question is, how can I read the data and prevent my program from crashing in case unexpected type has been received?

This is the way I am doing it now: (I am having default values in a constants file)

```
//
                    // data is documentSnapshot.data()
                    // fieldName is a String for field name
                    if let receivedFieldData = data![fieldName]{
                        print(defaultValue!)
                        print(type(of: defaultValue!))

                        if defaultValue! is Double{
                            userData![fieldName] = receivedFieldData as? Double ?? defaultValue
                        } else if defaultValue! is Bool{
                            userData![fieldName] = receivedFieldData as? Bool ?? defaultValue
                        } else if defaultValue! is Int {
                            userData![fieldName] = receivedFieldData as? Int ?? defaultValue
                        } else if defaultValue! is String {
                            userData![fieldName] = receivedFieldData as? String ?? defaultValue
                        } else {
                            // no data type met
                        }
```

Comment: You will have to check the types and values of all fields that you read, and make sure that they are what you expect, or convert them accordingly.This is the standard practice for schemaless databases like Firestore.  Since you tagged this with "swift", you will have to learn how to dynamically check the types of values at runtime.

Comment: Can I have a concrete example?  @DougStevenson Thanks much

Comment: Could you edit your question with a concrete example with code that doesn't work the way you expect?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: updated @DougStevenson

Comment: I would suggest that having *extra people that can edit the database datatypes* is a bad idea. If you don't have control of your fields, you're going to have a heck of a time with queries and maintaining data integrity. For example, suppose you have a users collection with documents that have field `Age` that's an Int type. Performing a query of users ordered by Age works fine as long as they are Int's but if those are changed to a String, then the ordering is totally wrong; String and Int sorts are different (Ints sort 1,2,3,4..10, Strings sort 1,10,2,3,4).